# SqLite database corrupted after making an executable Jar using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jar, executable-jar

I have developed a small Java application using Eclipse. This application has a SqLite database that comes from a Jar file (sqlite-jdbc-3.6.14.1.jar). I want to deploy the application as an executable Jar so I have to include the SqLite jar in this jar. So to deploy, in Eclipse, I click on Export.../Runnable Jar File and this produces the executable Jar file. The problem is when I run the Jar, the application opens and I can see that the database got corrupted: the records of every database tables have wrong data. The data is ok when I run the application using Eclipse.

Can you tell me what is going on and how I can deploy the application so the database will not get corrupted?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that I was having an old version of Eclipse which has a bug. I simply got the new version of Eclipse and the problem is resolved. After exporting the project, go to location of project and put runnable jar in folder `bin` then run everything okay.